# Can I use Javascript to split up an MP3 file into smaller MP3 files?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am making a game using only HTML5 and Javascript. I want to take an MP3 file the user selects, and split into few second long chunks. Is it possible to do this in Javascript, and if so, how?

Comment: Find a library that does this, or create one yourself.

Comment: I think you will have a better time with this if you use some... server-side code. :-\.

Comment: @Zéychin: javascript is server-side these days. What a bizarre world. Before you know, we'll be running PHP as browser scripting language :-)

Comment: Very hardly. This definitely calls for a server-side solution.

Comment: Theoretically it can be done. Because MP3 file is just sequence of bytes, right, so it can be loaded into JS as bytes array and then you can split it into 3 new ones. But you need to know the mp3 format to know what else should be done on these chunks. And as previous orators said it's much more convenient to use any other technology like C++ or C# on the server-side because here you can find easy-to-use and ready-to-use solutions. In order to make the process transparent for the users use AJAX to send the original file and to get results files.

Comment: *Atwood's Law: any application that can be written in JavaScript, will eventually be written in JavaScript.*

Comment: @SergeiTulentsev: I stand dumbfounded. Web applications are not my domain, so I wouldn't have known this for some time had you not said anything. The idea of server-side Javascript makes me sad in ways that I can not express.

Comment: You can use FileReader (part of FileAPI) to split the file by bytes locally.
You'll get faster results (no need for network back-and-forth), severe browser support issues and probably a headache.

Comment: @Zéychin — That suggests your exposure to JavaScript has mostly been in the form of quick and dirty scripts on sites such as dhtmlgoodies dot com and not nicely engineered code that takes advantages of the beautiful parts of the language. Perl has a similar problem with its reputation for similar reasons.

Comment: @Rob W — I don't consider a suggestion as to why someone who has said "Web applications are not my domain" might have a bad impression of a language which is only just starting to become more widely used outside of that domain to be an attack of any kind, nor a defence of a language that a question is about to be particularly off-topic (leastways, no more than the comment to which it was a response).

Answer (score 10):

If you need a client side solution, but are not bound to Javascript, you may want to give Flash a try. There is many excellent solutions for editing in Flex/Actionscript. Here is one tutorial I came across after a quick google: http://scriptplayground.com/tutorials/as/Play-Sound-Samples-From-One-File-Using-ActionScript-3/

However, if you are dead set on using Javascript, try following these steps:

1. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewodri/PKPD6/. It is using the HTML5 audio element to play a sound, but the interesting thing is that this data is encoded as a data URI. Whatever encoded data we throw at the source, it will be able to play.
2. Read up on the [W3C File API specification](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#filereader-interface), and especially the [FileReader interface](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-filereader). The is support for this in [Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/developers/web-platform-status#TOC-File-APIs) and [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications) at least, although I am not too sure how comprehensive it is. You will notice that you are able to [read the binary data into a data URI](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#dfn-readAsDataURL), which you can 1) manipulate as a string, and 2) send to the src attribute of the audio element.
3. This is going to be the hardest part... You can start by getting familiar with the structure of an MP3 file; ie. [understanding how big the ID3 tag is and how to identify it, how big frames are and where you can chop them off, and how the file is closed](http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm). The will help you extract relevant information, but also figure out where you can start chopping. I put some references at the bottom. A lot of similar code has been created for this in Actionscript which may be a good reference.

If you have enough patience, you can do the following:

1. Retrieve the binary data of the uploaded file, and convert that into a data URI
2. Determine how big the ID3 tag is when encoded in base64 (base64 represents 6 bits with 1 character), and save that code to variable
3. Determine how big each audio frame is, and build an array of all the audio frames
4. Determine how the file is closed, and save that code into a variable
5. Stitch it all together however you like, with the ID3 at the front, your selected frames in the middle, and file closure code
6. Send it to the src attribute of the audio element

I would conclude by saying that it would be far, far easier to do this in Flash, or even to send it to the server as mentioned in other comments. But if you have the justification for doing it all in Javascript, this is definitely possible in most modern browsers.

Additional References:

- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/
- http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/MP3Format.html
- http://www.mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm
- http://www.aardwulf.com/tutor/base64/base64.pdf
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Miscellaneous/Base64